# CNAME file for my github pages site is not working

Tags: web, github-pages

I have set up my cname file so that my mattmaginniss.github.io is being displayed as matthewmaginniss.com.

I followed the instructions carefully and the settings tab says that my website is being published at www.matthewmaginniss.com so yay!

So the next step says "Configure DNS settings"

After you've created and committed your CNAME file on GitHub, do one of the following with your DNS provider:
If your custom domain is a subdomain (recommended), configure a CNAME record.

If your custom domain is an apex domain, configure an ALIAS, ANAME, or A records.

This is where i am stumped, I don't know who my DNS provider is, i don't even know how to figure that out. I've been dealing with this for a few hours, and googling tirelessly has left me empty handed and lacking answers.

p.s.  plan to redirect my domain mattmaginniss.com purchased with google domains to redirect to this website. If that gives you anything that can better help you in helping me,  I'd like you to know. Thank you for any help you have to offer.

Comment: i realized that no less than 5 minutes ago. I just read your comment and jokes on you! I do own it _now_. Haha, thank you for being a good sport and not grabbing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't own the domain `matthewmaginniss.com`](http://who.is/whois/matthewmaginniss.com), which is probably why you can't figure out who your DNS provider is. You don't have one.

Your solution is to purchase the domain name through the registrar of your choice and register the CNAME or A records the same way you did for `mattmaginniss.com`. Google Domains will do fine if you prefer that. You should do it rather quickly before someone else buys it before you.

Comment: i realized that no less than 10 minutes ago. I just read your comment. So i do own it _now_ also, thank you for being a good sport and not grabbing it.

Comment: By the way, my confusion came in because i owned mattmaginniss.com and not matthewmaginniss.com really basic stuff. Lol it happens though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I realized my issue **I didnt own the domain**. Now that i purchased it and have fixed it. I set up DNS settings with GoogleDomains so that it looked like this.

[image: DNS Settings]

The IPv4 addresses are the locations github pages serves.

I hope that if you are having the same issues, you follow what i did and it gets rectified.